# Return multiple values from a function in swift

Tags: function, swift, return

How do I return 3 separate data values of the same type(Int) from a function in swift?

I'm attempting to return the time of day, I need to return the Hour, Minute and Second as separate integers, but all in one go from the same function, is this possible?

I think I just don't understand the syntax for returning multiple values. This is the code I'm using, I'm having trouble with the last(return) line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
func getTime() -> Int
{
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: date)
    let hour = components.hour
    let minute = components.minute
    let second = components.second
    let times:String = ("\(hour):\(minute):\(second)")
    return hour, minute, second
}
```

Comment: return NSArray(objects: hour, minute, second)

Comment: The "Swift Programming Language" iBook actually has a section titled "Functions with Multiple Return Values" ...

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Return a tuple:

```
func getTime() -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    ...
    return ( hour, minute, second)
}
```

Then it's invoked as:

```
let (hour, minute, second) = getTime()
```

or:

```
let time = getTime()
println("hour: \(time.0)")
```

Comment: Note that a better solution might be to define a Time struct and use that instead of the tuple.

Comment: How would you call that swift func from an objective C method?  Curious how you would gain a handle to three returned values.  Would you use a dictionary, for example?

Comment: You wouldn't.  If you want to call it from objc you have to return a class (maybe a struct) not sure.

Comment: It's recommended to add name to the parameters: 
func getTime() -> (hour: Int, minute: Int,second: Int) 

Then get like getTime().hour

Comment: @BrunoLemos eh, I'm still going to go with the better solution is to define a Time struct and use that.

Comment: I guess end result looks much similar to struct otherwise , i would prefer to use tuple, why else the feature would have been available ?

Comment: We can't live without autocomplete, right? :)  
If your code like this; 
' func getTime() -> ( hour :  Int, minute : Int,second: Int) { ... ' 
than your intellisense works. 
Please update the answer.

Answer (score 86):

Also:

```
func getTime() -> (hour: Int, minute: Int,second: Int) {
    let hour = 1
    let minute = 2
    let second = 3
    return ( hour, minute, second)
}
```

Then it's invoked as:

```
let time = getTime()
print("hour: \(time.hour), minute: \(time.minute), second: \(time.second)")
```

This is the standard way how to use it in the book The Swift Programming Language written by Apple.

or just like:

```
let time = getTime()
print("hour: \(time.0), minute: \(time.1), second: \(time.2)")
```

it's the same but less clearly.

Comment: `the right answer can't compile right in swift 2.0`: wrong, returning an unnamed tuple in Swift 2 works the same as with Swift 1. See this [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOzsWRB_wiZHIq_AlDExw9rKUjV9hJeFiHo).

Comment: yes, you are right , but I get a compile error in a similarity context. I should find it why.

Comment: The compile error was not related, it was because of the CalendarUnit format having changed in Swift 2, *not* the tuple format.

Comment: Not like that, the compile error I talked about was appear in the code myself.

Comment: `time.hour` won't work anymore. Please update the code.

Comment: I tested it, it's still ok. And the usage is still in the latest document, ["Functions with Multiple Return Values"](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) from Apple.

Answer (score 15):

you should return three different values from this method and get these three in a single variable like this.

```
func getTime()-> (hour:Int,min:Int,sec:Int){
//your code
return (hour,min,sec)
}
```

get the value in single variable

```
let getTime = getTime()
```

now you can access the hour,min and seconds simply by "." ie.

```
print("hour:\(getTime.hour) min:\(getTime.min) sec:\(getTime.sec)")
```

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 3**

```
func getTime() -> (hour: Int, minute: Int,second: Int) {
        let hour = 1
        let minute = 20
        let second = 55
        return (hour, minute, second)
    }
```

**To use :**

```
let(hour, min,sec) = self.getTime()
print(hour,min,sec)
```

Answer (score 8):

Update **Swift 4.1**

Here we create a struct to implement the Tuple usage and validate the OTP text length. That needs to be of 2 fields for this example.

```
struct ValidateOTP {
var code: String
var isValid: Bool }

func validateTheOTP() -> ValidateOTP {
    let otpCode = String(format: "%@%@", txtOtpField1.text!, txtOtpField2.text!)
    if otpCode.length < 2 {
        return ValidateOTP(code: otpCode, isValid: false)
    } else {
        return ValidateOTP(code: otpCode, isValid: true)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let isValidOTP = validateTheOTP()
    if isValidOTP.isValid { print(" valid OTP") } else {   self.alert(msg: "Please fill the valid OTP", buttons: ["Ok"], handler: nil)
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Thanks

Comment: For better understanding: https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/tuple-in-swift-a9ddeb314c79

Answer (score 1):

```
//By : Dhaval Nimavat
    import UIKit

   func weather_diff(country1:String,temp1:Double,country2:String,temp2:Double)->(c1:String,c2:String,diff:Double)
   {
    let c1 = country1
    let c2 = country2
    let diff = temp1 - temp2
    return(c1,c2,diff)
   }

   let result = 
   weather_diff(country1: "India", temp1: 45.5, country2: "Canada", temp2:    18.5)
   print("Weather difference between \(result.c1) and \(result.c2) is \(result.diff)")
```

Comment: Output : Weather difference between India and Canada is 27.0