# Is there an objective reason I can't have a single-element tuple with an element label?

Tags: swift

In Swift up to and including Swift 3, I can't create a single-element tuple where the element is named. So `func foo() -> Bar` is fine whereas `func foo() -> (bar: Bar)` produces a compiler error.

I can, however, think of a few possible uses for this pattern, e.g.

```
func putTaskOnQueue() -> (receipt: CancellableTask)

func updateMyThing() -> (updatedSuccessfully: Bool)
```

...where the label is used to reduce ambiguity as to what the return value represents.

Obviously there are various ways I could re-design my apis to work around this limitation, but I'm curious as to why it exists.

Is this a compiler limitation? Would allowing element labels on 1-tuples  break parsing of some other piece of grammar? Has this been discussed as part of the Swift Evolution system?

**To be clear: I am not soliciting opinions as to the correctness of the examples above. I'm after explanations (if they exist) as to why this is not technically possible.**

Comment: Read about the [Mysterious Tuple Problem](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1186940/Lisps-Mysterious-Tuple-Problem). The hint is that Python multiple returns are a tuple. So as Swift has multiple returns then Swift has tuples. Also take a look at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531195/return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-swift).

Comment: That was an interesting read, Asterion. I'm not seeing how it applies to this particular question, though. Could you provide more context please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's due to limitations in the compiler. There are no one-tuples in Swift at all. Every `T` is trivially convertible to and from `(T)`. [SE-110](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0110-distingish-single-tuple-arg.md) and [SE-111](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md) should improve things, but I'm not sure it will be enough to make this possible and I don't believe any of the current proposals explicitly do make it possible.

It has been discussed on swift-evolution. It's not a desired feature of the language; it's a result of other choices.

The Swift Evolution process is very open. I highly recommend bringing questions like this to the list (after searching the archives; admittedly not as simple as you would like it to be). StackOverflow can only give hearsay; the list is much more definitive.