# Is there a way to randomly choose a function from your function list with multiple return types in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to be able to randomly pick on of these functions to be called later on so I can get a variety of questions like an addition question then a multiplication question and so on. I've used this before but only for a specific return type and not many. I was wondering if anyone knows how to make it so I can use it with multiple returns. I don't want to just call some parts of the function because I need every part to make the game work. I've tested the game with just the additionQuestions and it works just the way I wanted it to. Now i want to be able to change up the questions and not just have addition question, hence the random function.

```
// this is one of the functions I'm trying to randomly choose but all of them
// have the same returns
// function 1: 

    func additionQuestions() -> (String, Void, Void, Void) {
    var sum : Int = 0
    let firstNumberGen = Int.random(in: 0 ... 100)
    let secondNumberGen = Int.random(in: 0...100)
    questionLabel.text = "\(firstNumberGen) + \(secondNumberGen)"
    makeQuestionVar = questionLabel.text!
    print(makeQuestionVar)
    sum = firstNumberGen + secondNumberGen
    print(sum)
    answerInString = trueCorrectAnswerButton.setTitle( String(sum), for: .normal)

    if sum >= 20 {
        falseAnswer1 = falseWrongAnswerButton.setTitle(String(sum - (Int.random(in: 1 ... 10))), for: .normal)
        falseAnswer2 = falseWrongButton2.setTitle(String(sum - (Int.random(in: 1 ... 10))), for: .normal)
    } else if sum < 20  && sum >= 10 {
        falseAnswer1 = falseWrongAnswerButton.setTitle(String(sum - (Int.random(in: 1 ... 5))), for: .normal)
        falseAnswer2 = falseWrongButton2.setTitle(String(sum - (Int.random(in: 1 ... 5))), for: .normal)
    } else {
        falseAnswer1 = falseWrongAnswerButton.setTitle(String(sum - (Int.random(in: 1 ... 2))), for: .normal)
        falseAnswer2 = falseWrongButton2.setTitle(String(sum - (Int.random(in: 1 ... 2))), for: .normal)
    }



    return (makeQuestionVar, answerInString, falseAnswer1, falseAnswer2)
}

// this is the random function:

   func randomQuestions () -> () -> (String, Void, Void, Void) {
    let questions = [self.additionQuestions(), self.subtractionQuestions(), self.multiplicationQuestions()]
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count)))
    return questions[random]
```

Comment: yes it is possible, check tuple

Comment: check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531195/return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-swift

Comment: `func randomQuestions() -> (String, Void, Void, Void) {
    let questions = [self.additionQuestions(), self.subtractionQuestions(), 
    self.multiplicationQuestions()]
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count)))
    return questions[random] ` 

I tried this too @ShauketSheikh and it was only giving me the last one which is the multiplication function

Comment: debug your code, might be your other value are nil

Comment: you function implementation looks wrong, you added conditions might be all the time your flaseAnswer2 condition returning value

Comment: What's with that `Void` repeated three times in the tuple? `Void` elements are barely usable.

Comment: @Cristik I have the void because I have `var answerInString : Void` and this is later set to: `answerInString = trueCorrectAnswerButton.setTitle( String(sum), for: .normal)`  which is for setting the text of the button. I set it to return any, but the xcode error said to return it as a Void and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you've given to your own question ...

```
func randomQuestions() {
    let mathCase = Int.random(in: 0 ... 2)
    if mathCase == 0 {
        additionQuestions()
    } else if mathCase == 1 {
        subtractionQuestions()
    } else if mathCase == 2 {
        multiplicationQuestions()
    }
}
```

... is a poor way to go about this. You should do this in a Swifty way, and in a way that is generalizable. In Swift, functions are first class citizens. So you can make an array of them and pick an element of that array at random, and call it. All your hard-coded names and numbers then go away:

```
func callRandFunction(_ fs:[()->()]) {
    if let f = fs.randomElement() {
        f()
    }
}
```

And here's how to call it in your particular use case:

```
callRandFunction([additionQuestions, subtractionQuestions, multiplicationQuestions])
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out and I don't really need what I posted above. I don't know why I didn't think of this before but ... well here this is what I have:

```
func randomQuestions() {
    let mathCase = Int.random(in: 0 ... 2)

    if mathCase == 0 {
        additionQuestions()
    } else if mathCase == 1 {
        subtractionQuestions()
    } else if mathCase == 2 {
        multiplicationQuestions()
    }
}
```

And this works for what I need to do with my app

Comment: It may happen to work, but it's not a good answer to the question as posed.