# Getting sum of arrays by name

Tags: arrays, swift, sum

im making a personal app for my job. i want to list indigent's for each thing i make so i know what im gonna need for the day in weight.

so lets say like i have 3 different  things i can make

```
food 1 = sugar: 2, eggs: 4, cheese: 3
food 2 = sugar: 5, eggs: 4, brownSugar: 3
food 3 = flour: 2, eggs: 4, cheese: 3
```

so let's say today have to make 2 batches of food 1, 3 batches of food 2 and 1 batch of food 3.

it would output

```
Sugar: 19
Eggs: 24
Cheese: 9
brownSugar: 9
Flour: 2
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction on going about this that would be great.. i was thinking set every food up as an array and try to add them each ingredients value by name.

Comment: You should show what you tried. People aren't going to show interest in helping you if it doesn't even look like you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of like:

```
var foodArray: [Foods] = []
// append all your foods in it when needed

func calculateAmount(foodChoices : [Foods]) -> (Sugar:Int, Eggs: Int, Cheese: Int) {

    var cheese = 0
    var sugar = 0
    var eggs = 0

    for g in foodChoices {
        if g.name == foodArray.name {
            cheese =+ g.cheese
            sugar =+ g.sugar
            eggs =+ g.eggs
        }
    }  
    return (Sugar, Eggs, Cheese)
}
```

You'll need to create a struct for your food and then you can work with it. Probably have better ways but this is the quickest I can think of

Comment: Awesome. Thanks I’ll give it a shot.

Comment: if you are confused on how to use the tuple that comes back, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531195/return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-swift 

Please mark the answer if it helped :) it would help me a lot

Comment: This isn't a good use case for a tuple. It doesn't scale well. There are only 3 ingredients now, but what if it eventually needs to support hundreds?

Comment: yeah I'm assuming there is only 5 ingredients as this point based on his question

Answer (score 0):

Since your food is basically pairs (ingredient: count) it will ideally represented by Dictionary where key is your ingredient (right now use `String`, later could be any `Hashable`):

```swift
let food1 = ["sugar": 2, "eggs": 4, "cheese": 3]
let food2 = ["sugar": 5, "eggs": 4, "brownSugar": 3]
let food3 = ["flour": 2, "eggs": 4, "cheese": 3]
```

This allow us easily combine them by using `Dictionary.merging(_, uniquingKeysWith:)`

```swift
food1.merging(food2, uniquingKeysWith: +)
/// ["sugar": 7, "brownSugar": 3, "cheese": 3, "eggs": 8]
```

Here we merge `food1` with `food2` and combine amount of same ingredients by summing counts.

And to merge list of foods we could use `reduce(into:, _)`

```swift
[food1, food2, food3]
    .reduce(into: [:]) { sum, food in
        sum.merge(food, uniquingKeysWith: +)
    }
/// ["sugar": 7, "brownSugar": 3, "cheese": 6, "flour": 2, "eggs": 12]
```

Here we start with empty sum (`[:]`) and merging in it all foods.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function orderFood(food1count,food2count,food3count){
    var sugarCount = food1count*2+food2count*5;
    var eggCount = (food1count+food2count+food3count)*4;
    var flourCount = food3count*2;
    var cheeseCount = (food1count+food2count)*3;
    var brownSugarCount = food2count*3;
    console.log('sugar :'+sugarCount);
    console.log('egg :'+eggCount);
    console.log('flour :'+flourCount);
    console.log('cheese :'+cheeseCount);
}

orderFood(2,3,1);
```

Comment: This is not Swift